# Insert a FOR JSON result into a table column

Tags: sql-server, insert, json

I have the a result of a `FOR JSON` expression, and I'd like to insert it into a table column.

How do I do that?

Here is one of my unsuccessful trials (note that the `SELECT hightrees ... FOR JSON PATH` part is correct, and can be seen in [the answer to my other question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/296308/111810), and here's also the [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a6e3017371852818255a919eed1fd945)), which gives the error `Invalid object name 'TreesJson'`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
  highTrees = JSON_QUERY(
                (
                  SELECT 
                  Id as id,
                  Type as type,
                  Height as height
                  FROM Trees WHERE [Height] > 5
                  FOR JSON PATH
                )
              ),

  lowTrees  = JSON_QUERY(
                (
                  SELECT 
                  Id as id,
                  Type as type,
                  Height as height
                  FROM Trees WHERE [Height] < 1
                  FOR JSON PATH
                )
              )
  FOR JSON
    PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) AS TreesJson;

INSERT INTO TreesGrowthLog ([Day], [TreesGrowth])
    VALUES (CAST(GETDATE() AS Date, (SELECT * FROM TreesJson FOR JSON AUTO))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way of doing this:

```
INSERT INTO TreesGrowthLog ([Day], [TreesGrowth])
SELECT 
        CAST(GETDATE() AS Date),
        (
            SELECT  *
            FROM
            (
                    SELECT TreesJson.TreesJson 
                    FROM (
                                SELECT 
                                highTrees = JSON_QUERY(
                                            (
                                                SELECT     Id as id,    Type as type,   Height as height
                                                FROM Trees WHERE [Height] > 5
                                                FOR JSON PATH
                                            )
                                            ),
                                lowTrees  = JSON_QUERY(
                                            (
                                                SELECT         Id as id,    Type as type,             Height as height
                                                FROM Trees WHERE [Height] < 1
                                                FOR JSON PATH
                                            )
                                            )
                                FOR JSON  PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
                    ) AS TreesJson(TreesJson)
            ) as a FOR JSON AUTO
        )
```

with values way

```
INSERT INTO TreesGrowthLog ([Day], [TreesGrowth])
VALUES(
        CAST(GETDATE() AS Date),
            (
                    SELECT TreesJson.TreesJson 
                    FROM (
                                SELECT 
                                highTrees = JSON_QUERY(
                                            (
                                                SELECT     Id as id,    Type as type,   Height as height
                                                FROM Trees WHERE [Height] > 5
                                                FOR JSON PATH
                                            )
                                            ),
                                lowTrees  = JSON_QUERY(
                                            (
                                                SELECT         Id as id,    Type as type,             Height as height
                                                FROM Trees WHERE [Height] < 1
                                                FOR JSON PATH
                                            )
                                            )
                                FOR JSON  PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
                        ) AS TreesJson(TreesJson)
            ) 
    );
```

and with CTE version:

```
;with cte as 
(
        SELECT TreesJson.TreesJson 
                    FROM (
                                SELECT 
                                highTrees = JSON_QUERY(
                                            (
                                                SELECT     Id as id,    Type as type,   Height as height
                                                FROM Trees WHERE [Height] > 5
                                                FOR JSON PATH
                                            )
                                            ),
                                lowTrees  = JSON_QUERY(
                                            (
                                                SELECT         Id as id,    Type as type,             Height as height
                                                FROM Trees WHERE [Height] < 1
                                                FOR JSON PATH
                                            )
                                            )
                                FOR JSON  PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
                        ) AS TreesJson(TreesJson)
)
INSERT INTO TreesGrowthLog ([Day], [TreesGrowth])
SELECT 
        CAST(GETDATE() AS Date), TreesJson
FROM cte
```

or use temp table #

```
SELECT * 
INTO #tmp
FROM (
  SELECT
  highTrees = JSON_QUERY(
                (
                  SELECT 
                  Id as id,
                  Type as type,
                  Height as height
                  FROM Trees WHERE [Height] > 5
                  FOR JSON PATH
                )
              ),

  lowTrees  = JSON_QUERY(
                (
                  SELECT 
                  Id as id,
                  Type as type,
                  Height as height
                  FROM Trees WHERE [Height] < 1
                  FOR JSON PATH
                )
              )
  FOR JSON
    PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) AS TreesJson(TreesJson);

SELECT * FROM #tmp;


INSERT INTO TreesGrowthLog ([Day], [TreesGrowth])
VALUES(
        CAST(GETDATE() AS Date),(SELECT * FROM #tmp /*FOR JSON AUTO*/) )
```

Comment: Can we make it work without nesting the entire query under the `SELECT`? Also, note that the inserted json escapes all double quotes with backslash, which is not desired.

Comment: What I mean is, can we make it work without nesting the entire query, but just using the alias?

Comment: @HeyJude  , with the help of `CTE` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15   … or use temp table, like the last query

Comment: Strangely, SQL Server displays a squiggly red line under `TreesJson(TreesJson)`, saying: *"TreesJson has more columns than were specified in the column list"*. However, the query executes successfully. Do you experience the same? Can it be solved?

Comment: @HeyJude: What you mean is, SSMS, not SQL Server proper, displays a squiggly red line.  Well, sometimes SSMS can't figure it out.  That specific scenario happens to me often.  I just ignore it.  It's annoying when you have to consciously ignore such things, because the squiggly line is there and is drawing your attention.  I don't think there's much you can do about it, though.  The principal thing is that your query is syntactically correct and is executed with the expected result.  SSMS is just an application that sometimes doesn't have a clue.

Comment: @HeyJude SSMS does a better job of figuring out columns in Table Valued Variables than temp tables, if that is the cause of the red squiggles. Switching to such has some other subtle implications, which may or may not matter.